# Find $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I tried to solve two examples in which i had to find  $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$ for $A_n = [-\frac{1}n, n] $ and $A_n = [\frac{4}{n+1}, 1+\frac{4}{n-1}] $ and write formal proofs. I am not sure if my proofs are correct or missing details. Can you check if my solutions are correct? If not, what should I do differently?

> $A_n = [-\frac{1}n, n] $ for $n \in \mathbb N_+$. Find $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$.

**Claim:** $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n = [0, +\infty)$

- $\boxed{\subseteq}:$ Choose $x \in \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$. Then there exists $m_0$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq m}A_n $. Then for every $n \geq m_0$, $x \in An$. 
  $x \geq - \frac{1}n$ and $n \leq + \infty$. Then $x \in [0, +\infty)$.
- $\boxed{\supseteq}:$ Choose $x \in [0, +\infty)$. It is enough to show that $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq 0} A_n$. Let's take any $n \geq 0$. I want to show that $x \in At$. If $x \in [0, +\infty)$, then $x \geq 0$ and $0 > -\frac{1}n$.
  $x \leq + \infty$, and $n \leq +\infty$. That is why $x \in \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$.

> $A_n = [\frac{4}{n+1}, 1+\frac{4}{n-1}] $ for $n \in \mathbb N_+$. Find $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$.

**Claim:** $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n = (0, 1]$

- $\boxed{\subseteq}:$ Choose $x \in \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$. Then there exists $m_0$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq m}A_n $. 
  Let's take $n=2m_0$. Then $A_{2m_0}=(\frac{4}{2m_0 +1}, 1+\frac{4}{2m_0 -1}). $
  $\frac{4}{2m_0 +1} > 0$, and $1+\frac{4}{2m_0 -1} \leq 1$ because $\frac{4}{2m_0 -1}$ converges to $0$.
- $\boxed{\supseteq}:$ Choose $x \in (0, 1]$. It is enough to show that $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq 0} A_n$. Let's take any $n \geq 0$. I want to show that $x \in At$. If $x \in (0, 1]$, then $x > 0$ and $\frac{4}{2m_0 +1} >0$.
  $x \leq 1$, and $1+\frac{4}{2m_0 -1} \leq 1$ because $\frac{4}{2m_0 -1}$ converges to $0$. That is why $x \in \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$.

EDIT:
**My second attempt to solve second example - $A_n = [\frac{4}{n+1}, 1+\frac{4}{n-1}] $ for $n \in \mathbb N_+$. Find $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N_+} \bigcap_{n \geq m} A_n$.**

First inclusion: 
Assume $x\in\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$. Then there exists $m_0$ such that $x\in A_n$, so for all $n\ge m_0$, $ x \in A_n$.
$ x> \frac{4}{n+1}$ and $\frac{4}{n+1} > 0$, so $x>0$.
Now I wanted to show that $x \leq 1$, but as I was trying to prove this, I started to wonder if $x$ really is $ \leq 1$. I tried to prove it by contradiction: 
If $x>1$, then there exists $m_1$ such that $x>1+\frac{4}{n-1}$. That's true, so I tried another approach:
according to the squeeze theorem if $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$, and $\lim a_n = \lim c_n = g$, then $\lim b_n = g$. 
Let $a_n = 1+ \frac{4}{n}$, $c_n = 1+  \frac{4}{n-2}$. Then $\lim a_n = \lim c_n = 1$ and $ 1+ \frac{4}{n} \leq 1+ \frac{4}{n-1} \leq 1+ \frac{4}{n-2}$, so $\lim 1 + \frac{4}{n-1} = 1$. So $x \leq 1$.

Second: 
Assume $x\in (0,1]$. I want to prove that $x\in\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$. Let's take any $ n \geq m_0$. $A_n = (\frac{4}{n+1}, 1+ \frac{4}{n-1})$.

Obviously $x \leq 1 \leq \frac{4}{n-1}$. Now, I am not sure if this idea is any good, but I tried to prove that $x>0$ by stating that $\lim \frac{4}{n+1}=0$. 
So $0 < x \leq 1$ and $x \in \bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$.

Comment: The second part of the first subquestion is incorrectly proved. Try to see why.

Comment: The set $B=\cup_{m\in \mathbb N} \cap_{n\geq m}A_n$ is the set of those $x$ that belong to $A_n$ for all but finitely many  $n.$ And the set $B$ is sometimes denoted as $\lim \inf A_n.$.......  For $A_n=[-1/n,n]$ we have $[0,\infty)\subset B$  because if $x\geq 0$ then $x\in A_n$ for all $n\geq x.$ And we have $(-\infty,0)\cap B =\phi$  because if $x<0$ then $x\not \in A_n$ for all $n$ such that $1/n<|x|.$

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are both correct but your reasoning is not. Note that $\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$ is the set of $x$ that are in $A_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, or if you like the set of $x$ which fail to be in only finitely many $A_n$. As such, it is unlikely that "most" elements are in $\bigcap_{n\ge0}A_n$, so when trying to prove equality of sets this is a poor way to go. I'll guide you through the solution for the first case (A_n=[-\frac1n,n]$) and let you handle the second.

Let's prove the first inclusion. Assume $x\in\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$. By your reasoning, there exists $m_0$ such that $x\in A_n$ for all $n\ge m_0$. But you stumble at the next step. Saying $x\le n\le\infty$ does not help you conclude $x<\infty$, but this bit is easy since $x\le m_0<\infty$ (we're dealing with sets of real numbers all along so the $<\infty$ part is automatic). To show that $x\ge0$, we need to proceed by contradiction: if $x<0$, then there is some $m_1$ such that $x<-\frac1n$ for all $n\ge m_1$. In particular, if $n\ge\max\{m_0,m_1\}$ this contradicts our assumption that $x\in A_n$. Hence $x\ge0$. This gives you the first inclusion.

Now for the second: assume $x\in[0,\infty)$. As I mentioned in the first paragraph, trying to show $x\in\bigcap_{n\ge1}A_n$ will not be fruitful. Indeed, if $x>2$ then $x\notin A_2$, so we have already failed. Instead, our particular $x$ cannot be larger than every natural number, i.e. there exists $m$ such that $x\le m$. Obviously if $n\ge m$, $n\ge x$ and $-\frac1n\le0\le x$. This implies $x\in A_n$ for all $n\ge m$, that is, $x\in\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n\ge m}A_n$. This completes the proof for the first exercise. Can you do the second?

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is much clearer to me. I have one question to your solution. Could you please explain how do we know that $x \leq m_0$? I can see that $x \leq n$ and $m \leq n$, but does it mean that $x \leq m$?

Comment: We know $x\in A_n$ for all $n\ge m_0$; in particular, $x\in A_{m_0}$. By definition, this means $x\le m_0$.

Comment: Thank you! I did the second example, and I hope that it's correct now. Can you check it, please?